# Speed-up apply with logical expression

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have data frame with 20K rows and expression similar to

```
df[‘res’] = df[vnames].apply(lambda q: ((q == 1) | (q == 12)).any(), axis=1)
```

It works but it takes quite some time.
Is there a more efficient way to run this?

Comment: You can just do `df['vnames'].isin([1,12])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
v = df[vnames].values
df['res'] = ((v == 1) | (v == 12)).any(1)
```

Comment: Much faster indeed